Swipper Css loading issue in React Application
I am facing an issue after integrating into React Application latest swiper and CSS are not loading and getting the below error. We have update in webpacker.config.js with CSS loader


yarn build
ERROR in ./node_modules/swiper/modules/pagination.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> :root {
|   /*
|   --swiper-pagination-color: var(--swiper-theme-color);
 @ ./client/src/components/organisms/AnnouncementDetailsDrawer.jsx 25:0-31
 @ ./client/src/components/containers/AnnouncementDrawerContainer.jsx 9:0-79 10:54-79
 @ ./client/src/components/containers/CommunityFeedContainer.jsx 26:0-72 89:88-115
 @ ./client/src/components/entryPoints/MainApp/MainApp.jsx
 @ ./client/src/components/entryPoints/MainApp/index.js 1:0-32 2:15-22
 @ ./client/src/components/containers/MainAppContainer.jsx 9:0-45 11:98-105
 @ ./client/registration/clientRegistration.js 4:0-77 6:30-46

ERROR in ./node_modules/swiper/swiper.css 14:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (14:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders




